# How to convert nsstring to nsdictionary?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have gone through following question.

[Convert NSString to NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998554/convert-nsstring-to-nsdictionary)

It is something different then my question.

My question is as follows.

```
NSString *x=@"<Category_Id>5</Category_Id><Category_Name>Motos</Category_Name><Category_Picture>http://192.168.32.20/idealer/admin/Picture/icon_bike2009819541578.png</Category_Picture>";
```

Now I want to convert this into a dictionary, something like this,

```
dictionary key = Category_Id      | value = 5 
dictionary key = Category_Name    | value = ???
dictionary key = Category_Picture | value = ???
```

I don't know how to perform this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with a regular expression...  Something like `<([^>]+)>([^<]+)</\1>` would grab the key into capture 1 and the value into capture 2.  Iterate over the matches and build the dictionary.

This uses [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net):

```
NSString  * x = @"<Category_Id>5</Category_Id><Category_Name>Motos</Category_Name><Category_Picture>http://192.168.32.20/idealer/admin/Picture/icon_bike2009819541578.png</Category_Picture>";
NSString * regex = @"<([^>]+)>([^<]+)</\\1>";
NSArray * cap = [x arrayOfCaptureComponentsMatchedByRegex:regex];
NSMutableDictionary * d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSArray * captures in cap) {
    if ([captures count] < 3) { continue; }
    NSString * key = [captures objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString * value = [captures objectAtIndex:2];
    [d setObject:value forKey:key];
}
NSLog(@"%@", d);
```

Comment: Sir, Would you give some more brief, please?

Comment: Sagar, check out the links I posted in your question on string matching. In general learning about regular expressions will be very helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633331/replacing-in-nsstring-with-wildcards-regular-expressions-cocoa

Comment: Glad to know sir. Very smart.

Comment: Was waiting for a long time. & finally Sir, Your brilliant Idea helped me a lot for creating custom parser.

Comment: a long time?  2 is hours a long time?

Comment: I was wondering about this technique & wanted to find out a solution. I didn't asked question. "A long time" isn't refereed for your answer sir. You are very quick in replying me.

Comment: @Dave Sir, I think @Chris have better option. We don't require get into regex. What's your opinion sir?

Comment: not being familiar with `NSXMLDocument`, I have no idea.  Looks like a perfectly legit answer to me.  What option you use is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 6):

Not the fastest implementation, but this would do the trick (and doesn’t require any third party libraries):

```
@interface NSDictionary (DictionaryFromXML)

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryFromXML:(NSString *)xml;

@end

@implementation NSDictionary (DictionaryFromXML)

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryFromXML:(NSString *)xml
{
  // We need to wrap the input in a root element
  NSString *x = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<x>%@</x>", xml];

  NSXMLDocument *doc = [[[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:x
                                                         options:0
                                                           error:NULL]
                         autorelease];

  if (!doc)
    return nil;

  NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

  for (NSXMLElement *el in [[doc rootElement] children])
    [dict setObject:[el stringValue] forKey:[el name]];

  return dict;
}

@end
```

Comment: I would totally go this route over a regex expression. Might be a bit more code, but it's way easier to understand, and to read. (At least by humans.)

Answer (score 5):

If it's XML then you can use an NSXMLParser. If it's not then you can write your own parser.

Comment: Your format is not XML. You have a pipe-delimited string in your post that you want to convert. You'll need to write your own parser.

Comment: And you'd prefer to represent XML text with a data type that isn't a string? What?

Comment: Data is in string & intended result should be in dictionary.

Comment: The pipe-delimited stuff in the OP is just pretty-printing the desired dictionary contents.