# stringByReplacing, with exceptions?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

Let's say I have the string:

```
@"(Mg(Ni+(N(O2)3";
```

I am wondering if it is possible to replace occurrences of the string "(" but with the exception of "+(". Thus result;

```
@"+Mg+Ni+(N+O2)3";
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this sort of more complex string replacements with [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

You can write the expression using a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to find a `(` that is *not preceded by* a `+` (though there are simpler alternatives in this case, see @sch's comment).

Example:

```
NSString *string = @"(Mg(Ni+(N(O2)3";
NSLog(@"Original string: %@", string);
NSString *pattern = @"(?<!\\+)\\(";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:NULL];   
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string 
                                                           options:0
                                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                                                      withTemplate:@"$1+"];
NSLog(@"After replacement: %@", modifiedString);
```

Comment: awesome works like a farm, now I just have to figure out how it works so I can use this trick in the future for myself :P thanks!

Comment: The regex `@"(^|[^+])\\("` produces the same result. So why is the negative look behind required?

Answer (score 2):

Read about similar problem with regular expressions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1633830/986169)

You can also do the following as a quickfix with no regexp (will work for simple formatted string like in your example) :

1. Replace all `+(` to `[`
2. Replace all `(` to `+`
3. Replace all `[` to `+)`

I assume `[` is not part of your string syntax. (If it is use a one that doesn't)

Answer (score 0):

There is a `NSRegularExpressionClass` that provides the following method:

```
-(NSString *)stringByReplacingMatchesInString:(NSString *)string options:(NSMatchingOptions)options range:(NSRange)range withTemplate:(NSString *)template
```

This is probably what you want.