# Objective-C – Replace newline sequences with one space

Tags: objective-c, replace, nsstring, newline

How can I replace newline (\n) sequences with one space.

I.e the user has entered a double newline ("\n\n") I want that replaced with one space (" "). Or the user has entered triple  newlines ("\n\n\n") I want that replaced with also one space (" ").

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSArray *split = [orig componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
split = [split filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length > 0"]];
NSString *res = [split componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

This is how it works:

- First line splits by newline characters
- Second line removes empty items inserted for multiple separators in a row
- Third line joins the strings back using a single space as the new separator

Comment: Thanks, accepting your answer as being the easiest for readability.

Answer (score 14):

3 times more performant than using `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet`

```
NSString *fixed = [original stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n+"
                                                     withString:@" "
                                                        options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, original.length)];
```

Possible alternative regex patterns:

- Replace only space: `[ ]+`
- Replace space and tabs: `[ \\t]+`
- Replace space, tabs and newlines: `\\s+`
- Replace newlines: `\\n+`

Answer (score 3):

As wattson says you can do this with `NSRegularExpression` but the code is quite verbose so if you want to do this at several places I suggestion you to do a helper method or even a `NSString` category with method like `-[NSString stringByReplacingMatchingPattern:withString:]` or something similar.

```
NSString *string = @"a\n\na";
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\n+"
                                                        options:0
                                                          error:NULL]
              stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string
              options:0
              range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
              withTemplate:@" "]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression, something like "s/\n+/\w/" (a replace which will match 1 or more newline character and replace with a single white space)

this question has a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633331/replacing-in-nsstring-with-wildcards-regular-expressions-cocoa) to a regex library, but there is NSRegularExpression available too