# NSString - remove more than 3 "newlines" from middle of NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Trying to remove unnecessary new lines (3 newlines and more) from middle of NSString

**string to delete middle new lines:** \n\n\n

```
Hello








my story is...
```

**goal:**

```
Hello

my story is...
```

**code with no success:**

```
    message = [message stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
    message = [message stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    message = [message stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    message = [message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n{3,}" withString:@"\n\n"];
    message = [message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r\n" withString:@"\n\n"];
```

Comment: `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` only removes from the ends, not the middle, so that's not a viable option.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23336689/1226963 (just change the replacement string as needed).

Comment: @rmaddy, your code answer is removing all string's new lines.
I'm looking to remove only **3 newlines and above.**

Comment: The answer I linked to is the general solution you need. Obviously you need to tweak the search and replacement strings to meet your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>    message = [message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n{3,}" withString:@"\n\n"];
> ```

You are almost there – you can't just use a regular expression as the first argument as the there is no way to tell the different between a string to replace and a RE to replace, they are both just strings...

What you need is the sibling method `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:`, you set the `options` argument to `NSRegularExpressionSearch` to indicate the first argument is a RE, and set the `range` to the whole string.

HTH