# Detect certain characters in a text field

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

What is the easiest way to detect a character in a text field?

I want to be able to detect a certain character and replace that character with another specific character.

So If I write in a text field... "zyxw" I want it to be replaced with "abcd".

I'm a newbie and don't really know where to start with this or how to go about it.  If anyone has any methods of doing this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Regex is probably the best bet you have to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you replace part of a string using [`NSRegularExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html), in response to `UITextField` delegate call of `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`:

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)txt shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)res{
    NSString *string = txt.text; // Suppose it's "Hello, zyxw!";
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"zyxw" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
    res = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:range withTemplate:@"abcd"];
    NSLog(@"%@", res);
}
```

Comment: this won't work... I want to be able to put in wxyz and it result in dcba, as well as xzyw and it result in cabd and so forth.  With this I can only type in zyxw and it changes.

Comment: @Craig Please read more on regular expressions, the pattern parameter (the `@"zyxw"` in this case) can be changed to recognize a great deal of different patterns by following very simple rules. The template parameter ( the `@"abcd"`) is also very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

For a "newbie" I would point to regular expressions (regex).

See [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) from Apple in reference to objective-c.

See this Stack Exchange [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633331/replacing-in-nsstring-with-wildcards-regular-expressions-cocoa) about Objective-C regex Support.

For more general info on regular expressions and how they assist pattern matching algorithms, [see here](http://www.digitalamit.com/article/regular_expression.phtml), or reference Google.